# No realiza sumatorio dentro del forEach en JSP

Tags: variables, jsp, sumatoria, taglib

Estoy intentando hacer una suma dentro del forEach pero la página me da error, concretamente me falla la parte de ${totalGryffindor **+ value**}" y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, en la parte superior tengo el siguiente código:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Map, java.util.HashMap, java.util.Set, java.util.Iterator" language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<% Map<String, Integer> gryffindorPuntuacions = (Map<String, Integer>) session.getAttribute("gryffindorPuntuacions"); %>
```

Debo remarcar que estoy usando Netbeans 11.2 con Glassfish 5.1.0 y Java 8, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${gryffindorPuntuacions}">
<c:set var="value" value="${entry.value}" />
<c:set var="totalGryffindor" value="${totalGryffindor + value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

```
<c:set var="total" value="${0}"/>
<c:forEach var="article" items="${list}">
<c:set var="total" value="${total + article.price}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Error exception

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException:
> Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key
> el.convert root cause
>
> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle
> java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key el.convert

Comment: ¿Has probado a quitar esa extraña variable "value" y a poner directamente en la expresión regular entry.value en su lugar? Quitar me refiero a eliminar esa línea c:set

Comment: Como [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27274790/2553194)

Comment: Buenas, lo he probado y me sigui dando error, concretamente: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key el.convert

Comment: Edita la pregunta con las modificaciones que hayas hecho y añade el stacktrace (la lista de errores que te salen)

Comment: Ahora lo acabo de editar, aunque el segundo código no sale con buen formato, no entiendo porque, he puesto la tilde invertida `

Comment: @TraudacioDacio son 3 tildes, no una sola ;)

Comment: ¿Puedes comparar tu código con el que te he enlazado en mi segundo comentario? Quizás así entiendas mejor qué te quería decir.

Comment: He puesto el otro código de ejemplo, ya he solucionado lo de las tildes también.